# Ограничение количества post запросов

Tags: jquery, laravel, post

Добрый вечер. Столкнулся с проблемой, имею сайт, на котором по кнопке выполняется покупка цифрового товара. Клик по кнопке отправляет post запрос на сервер, обрабатывает данные, отнимает баланс и выдает цифровой товар.

Сегодня нас взломали, отправив 25 команд на сервер за 2 секунды, по всей видимости сервер не до конца справился и баланс пользователю отнял в 10 раз меньше (Стоимость 1 товара 35 рублей, баланс у пользователя был 800, он купил 25 товаров, но баланс стал 700), я повторил его действия, используя консоль хрома отправил 20 копий команды $.post и результат был тот же, товары выдались, но баланс уменьшился лишь на 1/10 от необходимого

Вопрос такой, как можно ограничить количество запрос к 1 url от 1 пользователя скажем на 1 запрос в 2 секунды на стороне сервера? или может есть другие варианты решения проблемы?

Comment: "сервер не до конца справился" - не следует "очеловечивать" серверный код (кстати, что там у нас на сервере?). Запись количества купленных товаров и изменение баланса обернуты в общую транзакцию?

Comment: рекапчу в студию! и на регистрацию и на чекаут. а то они сейчас поналетят, халявщики

Comment: И поломали вас, похоже, не сегодня, если ещё и единицу товара посчитали по 4.

Comment: @Igor , Проверка по базам, выбор товара, списание баланса, возврат данных о товаре. Все в едином контроллере, фреймворк - Laravel

Comment: А если я допустим буду в сессию вставлять дату последнего нажатия кнопки и сверять, если прошло 2 секунды - продолжаем работу обработчика, если не прошло - блокируем, такой вариант подходит?

Comment: Не подходит. Тебе прилетят 50 запросов через 2 секунды

Comment: Операция продажи товара должна быть атомарной в контексте хранилища. Только транзакции. Либо костыли с семафорами. =)

Comment: @vp_arth время каждого нажатия кнопки заносить в сессию и сверять каждую обработку

Comment: Никто не собирается жать ваши кнопки

Comment: Заносить в сессию и проверять время ведь я буду на сервере, соответственно тогда не важно как к нему обратились, кнопкой или запросом в консоле

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54012/discussion-between-vp-arth-and-ilya78rus).

Comment: @vp_arth "There is no spoon" Матрица

Comment: никого не смущает, что скрипт скупает товар по 4р.?

Comment: Он просто не все запросы на уменьшение баланса обрабатывает почему то, транзакции не работают

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно завернуть критическую секцию в транзакцию.
Тогда операции снятия средств и регистрация факта выдачи товара либо будут выполнены полностью, либо не будут выполнены вовсе.

Также имеет смысл блокировать выбранные строки методом `lockForUpdate`, чтобы попытка конкурентного обновления вызывала не перезапись, а выбрасывала исключение(с последующим откатом транзакции).
В отличие от `sharedLock` этот метод также блокирует чтение строк в других транзакциях.

```
    DB::beginTransaction(); 
    try{  
        $user = App\User::where('id',auth()->id())->lockForUpdate()->get()->first()

        //делаем дела....
        $user->save(); 

        DB::commit(); 
    } catch(\Exception $e) { 
    DB::rollback(); 
       return $e; 
    }
```